# Window close(X) button event creating issue with open a popup in Extjs 4.2

Tags: extjs

We want to open a popup on click  close(X)  button of Main window and the window should open till we use confirm button.
The issue is main window hide(close) before confirm popup open and when we reopen main window then it is not showing and giving following error in console.
"Cannot read property 'show' of undefined"

```
Ext.define('Info.UI.Main Window',
{
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    id: 'MyWindow',
    modal: true,
    title: 'Main Window',
    closable: true,
    closeAction: 'hide',
    width: 515,
    height: 705, //695,
    layout: 'border',
    bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px;',
    listeners: {
        save: function() {
        },
        //close main window when click X button
        close: function() {
             //alert("Open confirm window");
             OpenConfirmationWindow();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You did not provide the code where `show` is called, so I can't help you.

Comment: No, its normal code show that window but just its happening when we call that close event and function  for Open confirm popup. without using X button and calling "OpenConfirmationWindow()" then  its working fine.

Comment: I cannot help you. The error is in the code you don't want to provide.

Comment: Please provide a [Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home) that exhibits the problem.

Comment: ok, i am showing the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you need to use [`beforeclose`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.window.Window.html#event-beforeclose) event of [`window`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.window.Window.html). In `beforeclose` event you need to maintain one `config` to check confirmation of window will be close or not.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2bjv)**, I have create a demo using your code and put modification. I hope this will help or guide you to achieve your requirement.

**Code Snippet**

```
Ext.define('Info.UI.Main Window', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    xtype: 'infoWindow',
    modal: true,
    title: 'This a new Window',
    closable: true,
    closeAction: 'hide',
    width: 300,
    height: 400,
    layout: 'border',
    bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px;',
    listeners: {
        save: function () {},
        //beforeclose main window when click X button
        beforeclose: function (thisWindow) {
            if (!thisWindow.isConfirmed) {
                Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Confirmation', 'Are you sure you wish to close this window before saving your changes?', function (btn) {
                    if (btn == 'yes') {
                        thisWindow.isConfirmed = true;
                        thisWindow.close();
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'My Panel',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        margin: 20,
        text: 'Open Info Wndow',
        handler: function () {
            //If window is already created then we can get using component query or Ext.getCmp();
            var win = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('infoWindow')[0] || Ext.create('Info.UI.Main Window');
            win.isConfirmed = false;
            win.show();
        }
    }]
});
```